# How to retain selection of Listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, selection

I have created a Simple listview demo, which has listselector.

A problem which i am facing is that the listview is unable to retain item selection when soft 
keyboard is open.

After selecting a list item, if i tap on edit text(which is outside of List view) to enter text, at time of softkeypad open, listview lost its selection.

How can i retain this selection on UI update?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted)

Comment: I didn't got solution from ur given link.