# Android Activity ListView Highlight case

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, highlight

It's very strange. I already [tried this steps given.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted)

But seems no luck. 
Whenever I click the item inside the ListView, 
the item is highlighted with black color. Instead of the blue color.
Which part that I wrong?

Here is my **activity_chat1.xml file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Available Peers"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pick one of the peers below : " />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:listSelector="@layout/list_selection"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_startchat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start to Chat" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and Here is my list_selection.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:drawable="@color/pressed_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@color/checked_color" android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>
```

an here is my **color.xml file**: (under res/values directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="pressed_color">#4d90fe</color>
<color name="checked_color">#ffffff</color>
<color name="activated_color">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: could you try to put list_selection.xml in **drawable** folder?

Comment: And then change to android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selection"

Comment: what the difference? the content is still same. @user3249477

Answer (score 1):

As the comments noted move the *list_selection.xml* to **res/drawable** folder

Also change the list's listSelector:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selection"
```

And finally, the **colors.xml** file is supposed to be in **res/values** and you reference the 
colors by using

```
android:drawable="@color/pressed_color"
```

Comment: still not giving me the exact result, @user3249477