# Why is my ListView item selected, but not highlighted after click?

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I'm working with the *Master-Detail Flow* and using a Custom `ListView`, which is defined by a `BaseAdapter`.

After user touches the *List item* it doesn't remain selected.

I thought I could solve it by defining a `selector`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Selected Item -->
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/background_dark" />

    <!-- Default Item -->
    <item android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

inside my `ListView` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/list_selected"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Hereby my `list_item_layout` xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/datahora" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my `CustomAdapter` class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<RowItem> rowItem;

    CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> rowItem) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItem = rowItem;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return rowItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return rowItem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return rowItem.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        RowItem row_pos = rowItem.get(position);
        // setting the image resource and title
        imgIcon.setImageResource(row_pos.getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(row_pos.getTitle());

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

And my `ListFragment` class, where the user click seems to be handled by the `Callback`:

```
public class ParametroListFragment extends ListFragment {


    String[] menutitles;
    TypedArray menuIcons;

    CustomAdapter adapter;
    private List<RowItem> rowItems;

    /**
     * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
     * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
     */
    private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

    /**
     * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
     * clicks.
     */
    private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

    /**
     * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
     */
    private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

    /**
     * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
     * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
     * selections.
     */
    public interface Callbacks {
        /**
         * Callback for when an item has been selected.
         */
        public void onItemSelected(String id);
    }

    /**
     * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
     * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
     */
    private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        }
    };

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public ParametroListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

         menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
            menuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);

            rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

            for (int i = 0; i < menutitles.length; i++) {
                RowItem items = new RowItem(menutitles[i], menuIcons.getResourceId(
                        i, -1));

                rowItems.add(items);
            }

            adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ListView listView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, 
                null);

        return listView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
        if (savedInstanceState != null
                && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
            setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
        }

        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
        mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
        view.setSelected(true);
        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
            outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
     * given the 'activated' state when touched.
     */
    public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
        // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
        // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
        getListView().setChoiceMode(
                activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                        : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
    }

    private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
        if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
        } else {
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }

        mActivatedPosition = position;
    }
}
```

I think this is enough to work, but I have no idea why is not being highlighted after all. Can someone please help?

Comment: post your list_item.xml code

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted

Comment: @JigneshJain but setSelected(true) may cause adapter to redraw data, or it's not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @jyomin provided a solution to my problem it may generate a few bugs:

- When user scrolls (down or up) enough to *hide* the selected item, it will return to the *unselected* state.
- If user touches the screen (at any place) it will *remove* the `ListView` item focus.

That being said (and *tested*), I decided to find another workaround to my old code, as I want to not only **highlight** but **activate** the `ListView` item.

I found out that I was setting the background behavior at the wrong place. It should have been set before at the `LinearLayout` inside `list_item_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@layout/list_selected" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/datahora" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@layout/text_selected"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Simply added the **activated** state to the `View`:

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

        view.setSelected(true);
        view.setActivated(true);

        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);

    }
```

And defined a new selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Selected Item -->

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    <item android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

    <!-- Default Item -->
    <item android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

Way to go, Machado. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add below lines in your listview xml.

```
  android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
  android:divider="@null"
  android:dividerHeight="0.0sp"
  android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
```

Comment: Awesome. Would you please explain what's going on? Why was it not working?

Comment: Is there anyway I can also change the Text color?

Comment: To change the text set textcolor property of textView   android:textColor="#ff0000"

Comment: i seriously dn't know whats wrong in your code why its not highlitening but the above provided solution is the best and optimal one according to me to do this task

Comment: I found the solution, please check my answer. Thank you anyway!