# Suggestion for implementing layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a android app. Requirement of app is to support multiple screen sizes. When I was going through tablet layout of app, I found something like this:

[image]

Here, as you can see, there are two fragments. Left side contains a listview and right side fragment contains detailed content of selected listveiew item. now problem is: How do I move the arrow (selected with red mark) up and down accordance to item selected in listView??

Comment: can you please elaborate the scenario.! and what you have done so far.!

Comment: See the edit please, I'm sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16190228/1167094). You could make the arrow part of the list view fragment but make it visually blend with the content view.

Comment: Yah, I guess, I got my solution.