# How to refresh all list items background color as default color in Android?

Tags: android, listview

How do you change the background colors of list items back to the default color in Android?

For example, I have five list items which change background color when they are clicked with the following code:

```
listItem = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutId);
listItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

However, later when I click another list item, my previous list items need to have their background color changed back to the default color.

Comment: Have you tried to change your listview's background color

Comment: Check out this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted
The selected answer is correct.

Comment: "Android ListView selected item stay highlighted"- i think this means only selected item background color changed.i did this one.at the same time i need to refresh previous list item background color with their default color.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom background in xml drawable folder and add to linearLayoutId background attribute in layout xml. If you show me the code, I can provide with an example.