# listview item changed color when code run listview1.setSelection(3) color item changed

Tags: android

in android programing...

how item of listview Automatically changed color when   run code 
\n
listview1.setSelection(3)  color item changed?

listname2=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer2);
 listname2.setAdapter(adapter5);

when

run this ( listview1.setSelection(3))

automatically color change
tanks help me...

Answer (score 0):

try this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25131125/1687010 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/16190228/5780734 and add your java class and layout for better solution

Comment: im not click in item... i m want automatically when code listview.set Selection(27) then color changed

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter you could have an array of booleans or even on the object that you use for filling the list a property item that represent if a position is selected or not and on getView() method of adapter ask for this variable and depending on it you paint it selected or not.

PD: you should try using recycler view.

Comment: TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boolf);

  String s1="false";
  String s2=txt1.getText().toString();


  if  (s1.equals(s2))
   {txt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);}
   else
   {txt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);}

Comment: run in adadpter but when want send change false not work

Comment: You could make a boolean array with the same size of your adapters items list, then you need a method to set selection true on the given index . Then on the getView() method of adapter your condition should be if(booleanArray[position] == true) /* color it as selected */