# android:ListSelector doesn't work on my ListView

Tags: android, listview, selector

I want to have an `onClick` that the `chatlist-item` changes it's color when clicked/focused. I don't want to use any Java code if possible.

I tried this:

chatlist_layout.xml

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selector">
    </ListView>
```

selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/ripple_material_light" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green_hsrt_1_default_CMYK_100_10_55_0" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/grey" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can read [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16190228/3832212)

Comment: Do you have custom list item layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem may be in ListView background. So try to add `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"`