# How to change the background color of the selected item?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using this code, but it just does nothing:

Added to my listview:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
```

Then xml files in drawable to control the diferent states

**@drawable/list_selector**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

**@drawable/list_item_bg_normal**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
  android:startColor="#ff0000"
  android:endColor="#ffffff"
  android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

**@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#ff0000"
      android:endColor="#ffffff"
      android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

In the Activity:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        view.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: I think you can use this also http://stackoverflow.com/a/16190228/4427519

Comment: means you want Highlighted color on to Selected List Item...?

Comment: Then...Please see this Tutorial....it is same as you want.....Please check..and let us know......http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change background color of selected item on a ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview)

Comment: @DharaPatel Just done, it does nothing :(

Comment: @xRobot...did you check it...and did solved or not..?

Comment: @SagarAghara I am checking, but it's different. I just need to change the background, not images and text.

Answer (score 0):

**Add**

```
adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

**Your Code Looks like this**

```
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            view.setSelected(true);
            adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

Comment: adapter is your adapter variable name. Are you using BaseAdapter

Comment: For Example       `ListAdapter mAdapter = new GroupAdapter(groupvalues, mrecyclerview);`    `mrecyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);`   in this `mAdapter` is adapter name

Comment: or can you post your full code for listview items add.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your selector file like below and call notify data set changed. And inside the adapter, you need to maintain a flag to maintain selection when the list is scrolled.

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal"/>
    </selector>
```

Then

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                view.setSelected(true);
                list.get(position).isSelected=true; // list is array items passed to adapter
                adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
            )
    }
```

In getView method of your adapter 
maintain selection by using a boolean like

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     if(list.get(position).isSelected){
       convertview.setSelected(true)
     }else{
       convertview.setSelected(false)
     }
}
```

Comment: I get this: Cannot resolve symbol "isSelected", Cannot resolve symbol "adapter",

Comment: adapter is reference to your adapter and "isSelected" is boolean varible you need to declare in your model class.