# How to trigger setOnItemSelectedListener in ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I run this code blow ,
and the `setOnItemClickListener()`  run well ,
but the selected event can not be triggered.
Is there something wrong or the ListView can't bind `setOnItemSelectedListener`?
Could somebody please help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private TextView selection;
private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
        "sit", "amet",
        "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
        "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
        "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
        "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,items);
    listView.setAdapter(aa);
    listView.setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selection.setText(items[position]);
        }
    });
    listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,items[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
  }
}
```

Comment: remove `setOnItemSelectedListener` and see once

Comment: @Redman it's worked ,and trigger the click event,but I just want to trigger the selected event

Comment: I don't think you want the onItemSelected listener. The normal click listener prevents that from happening. http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-multiple-selection-listview/

Comment: it will only trigger when you click an item in list view, you can know which item was clicked by using position as you already did,Keep the Toast from onitemselected to onitemclicked, i think you can see the string in toast

Comment: @cricket_007 but when I remove `setOnItemClickListener()` the selected event was not triggered also ; I'm very confused although it's just for practise .

Comment: @Redman My question is about `setOnItemSelectedListener`,and the click event is just for comparison. I tried remove click listener ,and the selected event not run also.

Comment: You keep the click event and you can get your selected items from that (see the link). You do not need the "selected" listener

Comment: @cricket_007 I got your point,  and  I know i'm chasing dead ends,thank you all the same

Answer (score 0):

I guess  you are taking about retaining the selected item as it is, if so then  add the following lines in your xml list view part

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
 android:listSelector="#666666"
```

your activity should be some thing like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private TextView selection;
private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
        "sit", "amet",
        "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
        "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
        "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
        "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
    ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,items);
    listView.setAdapter(aa);
    listView.setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selection.setText(items[position]);
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,items[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

  }
}
```

you may also follow other methods over   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted)

Comment: the `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` will conflict to `listView.setChoiceMode(CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)` ,and my key point is "why `setOnItemSelectedListener()` not be invoked even I deleted clicked listener"