# How to keep a listview item selected after clicking on it

Tags: android, listview

I have an android app which uses a ListView. When I click on any item, there is a light gray color which appears and fades out. How can I make this gray color to remain on the selected item instead of disappearing? Please take a look at the gif which shows the scenario which I want to avoid.

**Current Scenario**
[image: Current Scenario]

Comment: you can change the background color  clicked item when you click on the `onItemClicklistener`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector

Comment: Add a boolean variable for item state; suppose "isSelected" in modal class for arraylist passed to listview's adapter. Then onItemClick in getView() update this value accordingly further set background for selected/deselected and notifydatasetchanged(). thats it, you are good to go !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ListView selected item stay highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to change background color on clicked.

take reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16976534/3154636)

And then add this line inside your listview's OnItemClickListener

```
listView.setSelection(int position);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set item Selected according to your need using this method

```
 listView.setSelection(0);
 listView.getSelectedView().setSelected(true);
```

OR

```
 listView.setItemChecked(0, true)
```